# Error trying to display editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text1" />


<CheckBox
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/check"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text2" />

 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mazda" />
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toyota" />
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nissan" />
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hyundai" />
   </RadioGroup>

   <EditText
       android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
android:id="@+id/etext1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></EditText>



 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>

   package nidhin.survey;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SurveyActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener

{
CheckBox cb;
String myChoice;

RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
RadioButton radio3;
RadioButton radio4;
RadioGroup rg;
EditText text1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
    radio1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    radio2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    radio3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    radio4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1);
    text1.setText(myChoice);
}



  cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
       boolean isChecked) 
       {
               if (isChecked)
               {
                cb.setText("This checkbox is: checked");
               }
               else
               {
                cb.setText("This checkbox is: unchecked");
               }
       }   
    }
    );


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button); // through XML file
    Button1.setText("Click to display updated time");


    Button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button2.setText("Not Pressed yet");

    Button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button3.setText("Press for image");

}

public void myButton1 (View view)
{
updateTime();
}

public void myButton2 (View view )
{

Button2.setText("Pressed");
}

public void myButton3 (View view)
{
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//image.setVisibility(1);
}



private void updateTime()
{
    Button1.setText(new Date().toString());
}
}
```

I have a program which displays a checkbox , radiogroup and editText box. But the problem is that the edit Text Box does not show up. CheckedBox and radio buttons show up but not edit text box. In the main.xml file , if you place the editText box above he radiogroup , then the program crashes. Edit Text not declared properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Change your Radiogroup attributes to

```
         <RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/rg"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
```

You used as fill_parent for layout_height attribute.

Answer (score 1):

RadioGroup atts `android:layout_height` is `fill_parent`, please change to `wrap_content`